# Jquery: On enter focus next input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to focus the next input type when the user presses on enter by using Jquery. However, it doesn't detect the keypress for some reason.

The input types are inside a css class named mGrid.

```
function addFocusSupport() {
    $(".mGrid").find('input').each(function (index, element) {
        // Here we get all the TextFields
        alert($(this));
        $(this).on("keypress",
            function (e) {
                if (e.KeyCode() === 13) {
                    // Focus next textfield
                    alert("Enter Pressed");
                    var nextElement = $('[index="' + (this.Index + 1) + '"]');
                    nextElement.focus();
                    alert(nextElement);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                // TODO: For last TextField, do nothing
            });
    });
}
```

So what I am trying to do:
The user fills in the first input, press enter and automatically the next text box is selected. See it as a tab pressed.

But the event after      `if (e.KeyCode() === 13) {` is never triggered?

Comment: it's `e.keyCode` with a minus k

Comment: `keyCode` is not a function.so use `e.keyCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change:**

`if (e.KeyCode() === 13) {`

**To:**

`if (e.which === 13) {`

---

`KeyCode()` is not the proper way to get the keycode. You are thinking of `event.keyCode`, which is deprecated. If you are using jQuery, `event.which` is normalized to work on all browsers. Without jQuery, make sure you check all cases:

`var key = event.which || event.charCode || event.keyCode`

---

To focus the next input element, do this:

`$(this).next('input').focus();`

Comment: Thanks. This triggers the alert. So the event is pressed. now I just have to debug why it's not putting the focus on next txtbox

Comment: @Катерина Good to hear. I have updated my answer regarding the focus on the next textbox.

Comment: I've switched it to Event which, although the focus isn't working for me

Comment: @Катерина could you show us your current code? `$(this).next('input')` will find the immediate sibling of `this`. Are your input elements siblings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687825/asp-jquery-focus-next-textbox-from-gridview

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the following code is working fine.

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
    focusable = form.find('input').filter(':visible');
    next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
    if (next.length) {
        next.focus();
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm when inputs are not siblings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code

```
$(function() {
  $(".mGrid >input").off('keyup').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      $(this).next('input').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

here a working Jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/55j6L92k/)

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks alot. I see that there is something else going wrong somewhere in the code then, as the fiddle works correctly!