# How to move from first row's input field to last row's input field one by one in HTML table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here I've a HTML table with input field like this way

```
<td><input></td>
```

and there is a lots of row in my table. What I'm trying to do is that, when I will press enter button it will move to its next input field on the next row. For clear visualization

[image]

First I'll be in the input field 1 and after pressing the enter I want to move to the input field 2 and so on. It's dynamic table and id's are not maintaining any serial. Here I forgot to mention, there will be other input field as well and pressing the enter I don't want to go to the other column input field.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You'll have to find some way of keeping track, with text, or placing the cursor in a particular cell and saving that cell's row and column in a hidden field or something.

Comment: Yes, But i tried with the id but as I said, the id's are not ordered.

Comment: Updated my comment.

Comment: Try follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682428/jquery-on-enter-focus-next-input

Comment: Add an event listener to each input field so when it detects the enter key, it executes `$(this).parent().next().find('input').focus()` to find the next input field and give it focus.